# Hyperledger Fabric Warning. This orderer is running in compatibility mode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

After some time (stopping / restarting network),

Hyperledger Fabric orderers are giving warnings:

```
[orderer.consensus.kafka] processRegular -> WARN 02a [channel: mychannel] 
This orderer is running in compatibility mode
```

How we should solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the teardown script inside the basic-network folder if you have it, otherwise you can just stop all of your containers and if needed remove images too, then restart fabric with the script and you should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This message from below the line in Hyperledger fabric code.
code is snippet is from **chain.go** , located at - fabric/orderer/consensus/kafka

`if regularMessage.Class == ab.KafkaMessageRegular_UNKNOWN || !chain.SharedConfig().Capabilities().Resubmission() 
{
 logger.Warningf("[channel: %s] This orderer is running in compatibility mode", chain.ChainID())
 chdr, err := utils.ChannelHeader(env)
 if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("discarding bad config message because of channel header unmarshalling error = %s", err)
}`

This basically indicates that received regular message of type UNKNOWN or resubmission if off, indicating an ordering service network is with v1.0.x orderer

So it is not a error which needs to be solved, your network would be working fine.